# How to print a matrix of a multiple lists

Tags: python, list, io

I'm trying to print a matrix of a list of lists.

For example the input could be:

```
l1 = [[2,3],[3,2]]
l2 = [[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
l3 = [[1,1],[1,3],[3,1]]
```

The output should be based on coordinates. More specific: I'm searching the lists to see which one contains the coordinate and then I print the name of the list in which I found the coordinate.

Edit (thanks to @sweeneyrod): Every coordinate will be (only once) in a list.

For example: l1 contains [2,3], so on that place in the matrix "l1" is printed.
Another example: l3 contains [1,1], so on position (1,1), l3 is printed.

Output:

```
l3 l2 l3
l2 l2 l1
l3 l1 l2
```

I thought it'd be possible to iterate using a rowCount and columnCount but I don't succeed to get this working.

Any tips? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to be more clear about your output.

Comment: Do you have a guarantee that every coordinate will be in one of the lists?

Comment: @sweeneyrod Yes indeed, every coordinate will be in one of the lists (only once). Also added this to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> l1 = [[2,3],[3,2]]
>>> l2 = [[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
>>> l3 = [[1,1],[1,3],[3,1]]
>>> b=[l1,l2,l3]
>>> import numpy as np:
>>> a=np.zeros((3,3),dtype=str) # numpy array of empty strings
>>> a
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> for i,j in enumerate(b):
...    for k in j:
...       a[k[0]-1][k[1]-1]='l'+str(i+1)
... 
>>> for i in a: print i
... 
['l3', 'l2', 'l3']
['l2', 'l2', 'l1']
['l3', 'l1', 'l2']
```

Initialize matrix without numpy:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> cols=3
>>> rows=2
>>> a = [[0]*rows for i in range(cols)]
>>> a
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working like this. Any chance you'd also know how to generate a matrix like a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] using a number of columns/rows?

Comment: You could use numpy. I'll upload the codeline in my answer.

Comment: Hmm weird. I can't use numpy in Python 3.4.2. I don not always have a n*n matrix. Sometimes I'm using a n*m matrix. That's why I tried doing this: 
`a1=[]
a=[]
for i in range (0,columns):
    a1.append(0)
for i in range (0,rows):
    a.append(a1)`

The result looks the same as a self made a = [[],[],etc.] but it does not work.. This is really weird.

Comment: @TomVerstraete, I've uploaded the code to initialize an nxm matrix without using numppy. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to put those variables in a list (or do some bad and ugly introspection):

```
lists = [l1, l2, l3]
```

Then, have two nested `for` loops iterating over the coordinates:

```
for y in range(max_y):
    for x in range(max_x):
        for index, value in enumerate(lists):
            if [x, y] in value:
                print("l{}".format(value), end=" ")
                break
    print()
```

The function `enumerate` iterates over something and its indices:

```
list(enumerate(["a", "b", "c"])) == [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```